# Sequences of length $n$ made of digits $2, 3, 5, 6$ that no element of sequence divides the next one and that the first element is $5$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Determine the number of such sequences of length $n$ formed from the digits $2, 3, 5, 6$ that no element of sequence divides the next one and that the first element is $5$.

Form a suitable equation or system of recursive equations and determine the general formula.

---

MY SOLUTION:

So, we have that:

- after $2$ there can be: $3, 5$
- after $3$ there can be: $2, 5$
- after $5$ there can be: $2, 3, 6$
- after $6$ there can be: $2, 3, 5$

Therefore we can distinguish $2$ groups of digits:

- group $C = 2$ and $3$
- group $B = 5$ and $6$

There are 2 possible movements between those:

- form a digit from group $C$ we go to a digit group $C$ and a digit group $B$
- from a digit from group $B$ we go to $2$ digits from group $C$ and one digit from group $B$

Therefore I came up with an equations ($c =$ number of sequences with digit from the group $C$ at the end, $b =$ number of sequences with digit from the group $B$ at the end):

- $c_n = 2b_{n-1} + c_{n-1}$,
- $b_n = b_{n-1} + c_{n-1}$

---

Now I try to solve those to get $B$: $c_n = 2b_{n-1} + c_{n-1} \implies c_n = b_{n-1} + b_n$

And from that: $b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2} + b_{n-1} = 2b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$

So, for $B$:
$$b_n = 2b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$$

For $C$: $c_n = 2b_{n-1} + c_{n-1} \implies b_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2}c_n - \frac{1}{2}c_{n-1}$

And from that: $b_n = b_{n-1} + c_{n-1} \implies b_n = \frac{1}{2}c_n - \frac{1}{2}c_{n-1} + c_{n-1} \implies b_n = \frac{1}{2}c_n + \frac{1}{2}c_{n-1}$

And from that: $c_n = 2(\frac{1}{2}c_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}c_{n-2}) + c_{n-1} \implies c_n = c_{n-1} + c_{n-2} + c_{n-1} \implies c_n = 2c_{n-1} + c_{n-2}$

So, for $C$:
$$c_n = 2c_{n-1} + c_{n-2}$$

From that I get:

- $b_n = 2b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$
- $c_n = 2c_{n-1} + c_{n-2}$

---

By solving one of them I will effectively solve both. Then I will just plug different values of first two elements of sequences to get specific equations without parametres ($b_1$ and $b_2$ for $b_n$,  $c_1$ and $c_2$ for $c_n$).

$\lambda^2 - 2\lambda - 1 = 0 \implies \left( \lambda - (1 - \sqrt{2}) \right) \left( \lambda - (1 + \sqrt{2}) \right) = 0 $

So I get:

$x(1 - \sqrt{2})^n + y(1 + \sqrt{2})^n$

I calculated manually the numbers of sequences for some of the initial values of $n$:

- $a_1 = 1$ (because we can take only $5$)
- $a_2 = 3$ (because we can take $52$, $53$ or $56$)
- $a_3 = 7$ (because we can take $523$, $525$, $532$, $535$, $562$, $563$ or $565$)
- $a_4 = 17$ (because we can take $5232$, $5235$, $5252$, $5253$, $5256$, $5323$, $5325$, $5352$, $5353$, $5356$, $5623$, $5625$, $5632$, $5635$, $5652$, $5653$ or $5656$)

I distinguished between $B$ and $C$ values:

[image]

- $b_1 = 1$ and $c_1 = 0$
- $b_2 = 1$ and $c_2 = 2$
- $b_3 = 3$ and $c_3 = 4$
- $b_4 = 7$ and $c_4 = 10$

---

Pluging in the first two terms for $b_n$:

- $b_1 = 1 = x(1 - \sqrt{2}) + y(1 + \sqrt{2}) \iff x = \frac{1 - y(1 + \sqrt{2})}{1 - \sqrt{2}}$
- $b_2 = 1 = x(1 - \sqrt{2})^2 + y(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 \iff 1 = x(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) + y(3 + 2\sqrt{2})$

And I plug the value of $x$:

$$1 = \frac{1 - y(1 + \sqrt{2})}{1 - \sqrt{2}}(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) + y(3 + 2\sqrt{2})$$
$$1 - \sqrt{2} = (1 - y - y\sqrt{2}))(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) + (3y + 2y\sqrt{2})(1 - \sqrt{2}) $$
$$1 - \sqrt{2} = 3 - 2\sqrt{2} - 3y + 2\sqrt{2}y - 3y\sqrt{2} + 4y + 3y + 2y\sqrt{2} - 3\sqrt{2}y - 4y$$
$$0 = 2 - \sqrt{2} - 2y\sqrt{2} $$
$$y = \frac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}  = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2}$$

From that we get $x = \frac{1 - (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2})(1 + \sqrt{2})}{1 - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - 1  + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{1 - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1 - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{2 - 2\sqrt{2}}$

I get:
$$b_n = \frac{1}{2 - 2\sqrt{2}}(1 - \sqrt{2})^n + \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right)(1 + \sqrt{2})^n$$

---

Pluging in the first two terms for $c_n$:

- $c_1 = 0 = x(1 - \sqrt{2}) + y(1 + \sqrt{2}) \iff x = \frac{-y - y\sqrt{2}}{1 - \sqrt{2}}$
- $c_2 = 2 = x(1 - \sqrt{2})^2 + y(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 \iff 2 = x(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) + y(3 + 2\sqrt{2})$

And I plug the value of $x$:

$$2 = \frac{-y - y\sqrt{2}}{1 - \sqrt{2}} (3 - 2\sqrt{2}) + y(3 + 2\sqrt{2})$$
$$2 - 2\sqrt{2} = (-y - y\sqrt{2})(3 - 2\sqrt{2}) + (3y + 2\sqrt{2}y)(1 - \sqrt{2})$$
$$2 - 2\sqrt{2} = -3y + 2y\sqrt{2} -3y\sqrt{2} + 4y + 3y - 3y\sqrt{2} + 2\sqrt{2}y - 4y$$
$$1 - \sqrt{2} = -y\sqrt{2}$$
$$y = \frac{\sqrt{2} - 1 }{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{2 - \sqrt{2}}{2} = 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

From that we get $x = \frac{-y - y\sqrt{2}}{1 - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{-(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}) - (1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})\sqrt{2}}{1 - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{-1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \sqrt{2} + 1}{1 - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \sqrt{2}}{1 - \sqrt{2}} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2} - 2}$

I get:
$$c_n = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2} - 2}(1 - \sqrt{2})^n + \left( 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right)(1 + \sqrt{2})^n$$

---

We know that the final equation needs to be a sum of $c_n$ and $b_n$. Therefore we get:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{2 - 2\sqrt{2}}(1 - \sqrt{2})^n + \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right)(1 + \sqrt{2})^n + \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2} - 2}(1 - \sqrt{2})^n + \left( 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right)(1 + \sqrt{2})^n$$
$$a_n = \left( \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2} - 2} + \frac{1}{2 - 2\sqrt{2}} \right) (1 - \sqrt{2})^n
+ \left( 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right)(1 + \sqrt{2})^n$$
$$a_n = \left(\frac{-2 + 2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2} - 2}{(\sqrt{2} - 2)(2 - 2\sqrt{2})} \right) (1 - \sqrt{2})^n + \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{2})^n$$
$$a_n = \left( \frac{3\sqrt{2} - 4}{- 8 + 6\sqrt{2}} \right) (1 - \sqrt{2})^n + \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{2})^n$$

The formula seems to work fine since:

- $a_1 = \left( \frac{3\sqrt{2} - 4}{- 8 + 6\sqrt{2}} \right) (1 - \sqrt{2}) + \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{2}) = 1$
- $a_2 = \left( \frac{3\sqrt{2} - 4}{- 8 + 6\sqrt{2}} \right) (1 - \sqrt{2})^2 + \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{2})^2 = 3$
- $a_3 = \left( \frac{3\sqrt{2} - 4}{- 8 + 6\sqrt{2}} \right) (1 - \sqrt{2})^3 + \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{2})^3 = 7$
- $a_4 = \left( \frac{3\sqrt{2} - 4}{- 8 + 6\sqrt{2}} \right) (1 - \sqrt{2})^4 + \frac{1}{2} (1 + \sqrt{2})^4 = 17$

Is that correct?

Is there any 'easier' way to do that, than:

- partitioning into $2$ difference equations,
- solving both of them separatly,
- pluging first values for both of them separatly,
- adding together.

?

Comment: Not *differential* equations; *difference* equations (or, *recurrence relations*).

Comment: Note that yor formula can be rewritten as $$ a_n = \frac{1}{2} \left(  (1 - \sqrt{2})^n 
+  (1 + \sqrt{2})^n \right) $$